# Incorporating microsoft managed recommended rules in GIT TFS 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2017, code-analysis, tfs-2015, code-standards

I tried using stylecop, but it is quite strict with lot of rules. I do not want to customize it by disabling certain rules. I want to document that I am using 'Microsoft managed recommended rules', which I used while coding in  VS 2017.

I want to incorporate the same rules in Git build process TFS-2015. Should I do code standard analysis during build definition? If not, how else?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to SO, I could not find a clear question, can you modify your post and define a question to solve? Please read> [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @DavidG. i want to apply 'Microsoft managed recommended rules' to the master branch. so, if i build it with wrong coding standards, it should throw build error. or is it possible to do the code analysis in branch policies where we set number of reviews and merge strategies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not able to do the code analysis in branch policies where you set number of reviews and merge strategies. 
Unless the reviews manually check the code and fail the review according to Microsoft managed recommended rules.

If you want to apply Microsoft managed recommended rules to your code. Simply add `/p:RunCodeAnalaysis=true` to the MsBuild commandline additional arguments.

For stylecop there is also a related [build task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=richardfennellBM.BM-VSTS-StyleCop-Task), if you want use this, you could add it in your build pipeline.

Finally just enable the **[Build validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/branch-policies#build-validation)** in your master branch policy. Set a policy requiring changes in a pull request to build successfully with the protected branch before the pull request can be completed.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I haven't implemented it yet. I will post if I face any issues. Thank you again.

Comment: It worked! Now, it is just throwing the warning. Is there a way to make it mandatory, and fail the build process if the coding standards are not followed in TFS 2015?

Comment: @AnjaliIyengar  Sorry there is no way to make it mandatory for now. To fail the build,one way is “treat warning as error” for specific build definitions, In the build definition specify /p:TreatWarningsAsErrors=True in the MSBuild argument field.This will override any setting from the csproj files. Another way you could be able to return warnings and errors from your powershell script using logging commands. With using `task.logissue type=error` you could fail the build task and then fail the build.